# How Much Bread For Her Budget?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

A woman is looking through a store and sees a sign for 2 dollar bread saying "For every 10 loaves you buy, you get each for only 1.9 dollars!" A pretty strange deal, but she decides to take it.

If has a budget of 10,000,000 dollars for the bread, then how much bread can she buy without going over her limit?

---

Please remember to explain your reasoning and hide your answer and reasoning behind a spoiler thing.

(P.S. She's rich and really, REALLY, likes bread, I guess)

Comment: I hope there's some trick which makes the obvious answer wrong. But I don't see how there possibly could be.

Comment: Do you mean you get the 10 pieces of bread ALL for 19 dollars (a.k.a. EACH for $1.90)?

Comment: @SpencerKerr Yes, but only if she buys all 10 bread. If she buys 19 bread, it will cost 37 dollars (19 from 10-bread deal + 18 from normal 9 bread) but if she buys 20 bread it will only cost 38 dollars (Two 10-bread deals) which would be the normal price for 19 bread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer:

> 5263157

Explanation:

> $\frac{10000000\times10}{19}(decimal~ignored)=5263150~and,~for~remaining ~15\$, +7~breads$

Comment: Good job! Exactly on point.

Comment: Thanks! and please tell me how to add spoilers..

Comment: I'm not actually sure. It must be something to do with the formatting options.

Comment: Put an exclamation mark ! after the > in a blockquote

Comment: No problem. You might want to read this before posting any more questions like this one http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2783/are-math-textbook-style-problems-on-topic